# Any problems with this approach to cancel/abort Async servlet processing

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-3.0

In an Async servlet processing scenario, I want to achieve cancellation of requests.
(Am also hoping to keep this RESTful)

Say, I have a code like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/quotes")
@ResponseBody
public void quotes() {
   //...
   final AsyncContext ac = request.startAsync();
   ac.setTimeout(0);
   RunJob job = new RunJob(ac);
   asyncContexts.add(job);
   pool.submit(job);
};

// In some other application-managed thread with a message-driven bean:
public void onMessage(Message msg) {
   //...
   if (notEndOfResponse) {
     ServletOutputStream out = ac.getResponse().getOutputStream();
     //...
     out.print(message);
   } else {
     ac.complete();
     asyncContexts.remove(ac);
   }
};
```

If the Client decides to cancel this processing **at the server-side**, it needs to send another HTTP request that identifies the previous request and the server then cancels the previous request (i.e stops server-side processing for that request and completes the response for it).

Is there a standard way to do this ?
If it is the case that there is NO standard way to do this and each developer does it as per their will and skill, I would like to know if my (trivial) approach to this problem is ok.
My way (after @Pace's suggestion) is:

- Create a "requestId" on the server and return a URL/link as
  part of the first partial responses (because I could get
  many partial responses for a single request as part of Async processing).
- The link could be, for ex:
  ***.../outstandingRequests/requestId***
- When needing to cancel the request, the client does a DELETE request on the URL and let the server figure out how to achieve cancellation at its end.

Any problems with this approach ?

Comment: It's not a standard approach that I know of but our team returns the URL /outstandingRequests/requestId and a DELETE to that URL is a cancel and a GET retreives the status which includes the operation results when the operation has finished. (PUT and POST are not supported).

Comment: +1. Makes sense. Infact, I edit my post to reflect your suggestion and keep it open to look for more inputs.

Comment: @Pace : I think you have answered the question. Can you post your comment as an Answer so that I can accept it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using long running operations/tasks in a RESTful sense it is best to treat the operation itself as a resource.  A post to the operations URL returns a URL you can use to GET the status of that operation (including the results when the operation finishes) and a DELETE to that URL will terminate the operation.