# Why is there no asyncContext.cancel()

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, asynchronous, servlet-3.0

While the Servlet 3.0 spec has *request.startAsync()* and *asyncContext.start()*,
why has it not provided a *asyncContext.stop()* or *asyncContext.cancel()* to initiate necessary clean-up on the server-side ?

Pls view this in the context of this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324553/any-problems-with-this-approach-to-cancel-abort-async-servlet-processing) to understand where I am coming from.

- One HTTP request starts the Async processing and returns a
  **.../outstandingRequests/requestId** link to the client.
- Another HTTP request calls DELETE on that link to cancel the request

In this case, if I had a way to clean-up the server-side (servlet container stuff like AsyncListeners), instead of having to call *asyncContext.complete()* which will probably try and send a response back to the client, it will make sense. Doesnt it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this scenario, call 1 is still hanging there, waiting for its response when call 2 comes in and wants to kill it.  In this scenario, why would you not want to call `complete()` on call 1, thus finishing that call so that client stops waiting?  You would probably want to set the status code to something other than 200 in this type of situation, but `complete` seems too be the best option given any scenario because it returns control back to the original caller and performs any request related cleanup work.

When a timeout happens, which is an error, the container calls `complete` (with a non-200 response code I imagine).  The scenario you describe is similar to a timeout (albeit a forced timeout), so why not do the same thing the container does.  Just call something like this before calling `complete`:

```
ac.getResponse().setStatus(500);
```

Any maybe write something to the output stream describing what caused this error.

Comment: Am worried about the side-effects of calling complete() in a cancel case: "Any listeners of type AsyncListener that were registered with the ServletRequest for which this AsyncContext was created will be invoked at their onComplete method.". If the listener's where to consider this as successful completion (trivial example: increment a SuccessfulRequestsHandled counter), I would run into trouble. It feels like overloading complete() with many meanings !

Comment: The onComplete call takes an AsyncEvent that allows you to access the HttpServletResponse.   In your listener you could check the status code and act accordingly if non 200. You could also build an abstract listener class that encapsulates this check and delegates to onError instead if non 200 status code. Then just have all of your custom listeners extend from this one.

Comment: Thats a workable solution ! But it still is a work-around ! I guess, if we stretch that argument, the AsyncListener could just do with a single callback method, say onComplete(), and then require the programmer to set the appropriate status code and determine if it is a timeout or error or success or cancel ! It can do away with onTimeout() and onError() ! I honestly feel the Async Servlet spec did not spend much time thinking about cancellation !